# Handling big data on iOS

Tags: ios, database, full-text-search

I have an app, which requires a data base of about 400.000 data entries, which change from time to time (like once per month). The total size of these data is about 20MB. We want to enable the user to:

- download all data at once for offline mode
- download individual data on demand and cache them on client side for offline mode
- check for validity of individual data sets
- build an index in order to quickly search through data

What is best practice to handle these requirements on iOS?

1. Is there an existing framework which cares about these requirements?
2. What would be the recommended technology set for these requirements? Like SQLite or something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should ship a copy of your database with the app. You really don't want every user to have to wait for a 20MB download to complete before they can use your app.

As for the infrequent updates, provide an API endpoint that your app can call with a date parameter and return all new/updated records since the provided date. Also provide an endpoint that returns the date of the last change to the master database. You can then use this date to check the validity of the data on the device (assuming the device data is readonly).

The main storage options for iOS are SQLite or [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html). As for frameworks that will take care of the synchronisation for you, [TICoreDataSync](http://timisted.github.io/TICoreDataSync/) is an option if you opt for Core Data on the device.

Comment: I think it's worth pointing out that SQLite and Core Data aren't mutually exclusive because Core Data is an object graph and persistence framework that can use (doesn't have to) SQLite as its persistent store.

Comment: If you're looking for a NoSQL solution, [TouchDB](http://labs.couchbase.com/TouchDB-iOS/) fits that bill.

Comment: What if i have differnt big database against different customers... How can i ship database with App. So for the first time i have to download all the data.... Now what will you suggest in this case...????